# Как сделать блок с текстом

Tags: html, css

Как сделать такой адаптивный блок с текстом?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что именно вызывает у вас сложность?

Comment: _«Как сделать блок с текстом»_ - берешь блок; берешь текст; и делаешь блок с текстом https://i.imgur.com/H89tkaU.gifv

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
body {
 display: flex; 
}

.text {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  padding: 20px;
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
<h1>Заголовок</h1>
<p>Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для текстов на латинице с начала XVI века. В то время некий безымянный печатник создал большую коллекцию размеров и форм шрифтов, используя Lorem Ipsum для распечатки образцов. Lorem Ipsum не только успешно пережил без заметных изменений пять веков, но и перешагнул в электронный дизайн. Его популяризации в новое время послужили публикация листов Letraset с образцами Lorem Ipsum в 60-х годах и, в более недавнее время, программы электронной вёрстки типа Aldus PageMaker, в шаблонах которых используется Lorem Ipsum.</p>
</div>
```